# Assigning value of img to value attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to achieve this:

1. 3 radio buttons are available and also 3 div's, each of them containing an img tag.
2. On click of any radio button, other 2 div's will be hidden.
3. On selection of any radio button, since 1 div is visible. I need to take img src from that div only and apply it to the value (attribute) of the input element with the id "testing".

This is my code:

```js
var radOne = $('#graphic-one-name'),
  radTwo = $('#graphic-two-name'),
  radThree = $('#graphic-three-name'),
  radParent = $('#testing');

radOne.on('change', function() {
  $('.two, .three').hide();
  $('.one').show();
  radParent.attr("value", ".one.attr('src')");
});

radTwo.on('change', function() {
  $('.one, .three').hide();
  $('.two').show();
});

radThree.on('change', function() {
  $('.two, .one').hide();
  $('.three').show();
});
```

```css
.one,
.two,
.three {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/100x100');
}

.two {
  background: #023432
}

.three {
  background: red
}

.one {
  background: #fff
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="graphics-select">
  <div>
    <input class="graph-init" type="radio" name="graphic-one-name" id="graphic-one-name" value="' . $mono_gram_font_graphic_1_sku . '" />
    <label for="graphic-one-name"><img class="image-one-graphics"  alt="" height="auto" width="auto" />One</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="graph-init" type="radio" name="graphic-one-name" id="graphic-two-name" value="' . $mono_gram_font_graphic_2_sku .'" />
    <label for="graphic-two-name"><img class="image-two-graphics"  alt="" height="auto" width="auto" />Two</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="graph-init" type="radio" name="graphic-one-name" id="graphic-three-name" value="' . $mono_gram_font_graphic_3_sku .'" />
    <label for="graphic-three-name"><img class="image-three-graphics" alt="" height="auto" width="auto" />Three</label>
  </div>


  <div class="parent">
    <div class="one">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
    </div>
    <div class="two">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
    </div>
    <div class="three">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <input type="text" id="testing" value="test" class="imagerep">
```

Comment: Just to make sure I unterstand your question correctly: You want the image source value, for example `abc.jpg` depending on the selection of the radios?

Comment: Yes, once radio button is clicked. Depending on the visible div (which contains img). I need to capture img src and assign it to the value attribute of the last input element (which has id "testing")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty basic: You select the item over the class (e.g. `.one`), then you select the first child element (the `<img>` element in this case) and then you read the `src` attribute. Done!

You need to change this line:

```
radParent.attr("value", ".one.attr('src')");
```

to this:

```
radParent.attr("value", $($(".one").children()[0]).attr('src'));
```

For the other two functions, add

```
radParent.attr("value", $($(".two").children()[0]).attr('src'));
```

respectively

```
radParent.attr("value", $($(".three").children()[0]).attr('src'));
```

to the end of the function.

Here's your full snippet with the updated code:

```js
var radOne = $('#graphic-one-name'),
  radTwo = $('#graphic-two-name'),
  radThree = $('#graphic-three-name'),
  radParent = $('#testing');

radOne.on('change', function() {

  $('.two, .three').hide();
  $('.one').show();
  radParent.attr("value", $($(".one").children()[0]).attr('src'));
});

radTwo.on('change', function() {

  $('.one, .three').hide();
  $('.two').show();
  radParent.attr("value", $($(".two").children()[0]).attr('src'));
});

radThree.on('change', function() {

  $('.two, .one').hide();
  $('.three').show();
  radParent.attr("value", $($(".three").children()[0]).attr('src'));

});
```

```css
.one,
.two,
.three {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.two {
  background: #023432
}

.three {
  background: red
}

.one {
  background: #fff
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="graphics-select">
  <div>
    <input class="graph-init" type="radio" name="graphic-one-name" id="graphic-one-name" value="' . $mono_gram_font_graphic_1_sku . '" />
    <label for="graphic-one-name"><img class="image-one-graphics"  alt="" height="auto" width="auto" />One</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="graph-init" type="radio" name="graphic-one-name" id="graphic-two-name" value="' . $mono_gram_font_graphic_2_sku .'" />
    <label for="graphic-two-name"><img class="image-two-graphics"  alt="" height="auto" width="auto" />Two</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="graph-init" type="radio" name="graphic-one-name" id="graphic-three-name" value="' . $mono_gram_font_graphic_3_sku .'" />
    <label for="graphic-three-name"><img class="image-three-graphics" alt="" height="auto" width="auto" />Three</label>
  </div>


  <div class="parent">
    <div class="one">
      <img src="abc.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="two">
      <img src="xyz.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="three">
      <img src="ghk.jpg">
    </div>

  </div>

  <input type="text" id="testing" value="test" class="imagerep">
```

Answer (score 0):

You were fetching the attribute of the element in a string while you had to had to select it as a method on the element.

```js
var radOne = $('#graphic-one-name'),
  radTwo = $('#graphic-two-name'),
  radThree = $('#graphic-three-name'),
  radParent = $('#testing');

radOne.on('change', function() {

  $('.two, .three').hide();
  $('.one').show();
  radParent.attr("value", $(".one").children(':first').attr('src'));
});

radTwo.on('change', function() {

  $('.one, .three').hide();
  $('.two').show();
  radParent.attr("value", $(".two").children(':first').attr('src'));

});

radThree.on('change', function() {

  $('.two, .one').hide();
  $('.three').show();
  radParent.attr("value", $(".three").children(':first').attr('src'));

});
```

```css
.one,
.two,
.three {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.two {
  background: #023432
}

.three {
  background: red
}

.one {
  background: #fff
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="graphics-select">
  <div>
    <input class="graph-init" type="radio" name="graphic-one-name" id="graphic-one-name" value="' . $mono_gram_font_graphic_1_sku . '" />
    <label for="graphic-one-name"><img class="image-one-graphics"  alt="" height="auto" width="auto" />One</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="graph-init" type="radio" name="graphic-one-name" id="graphic-two-name" value="' . $mono_gram_font_graphic_2_sku .'" />
    <label for="graphic-two-name"><img class="image-two-graphics"  alt="" height="auto" width="auto" />Two</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="graph-init" type="radio" name="graphic-one-name" id="graphic-three-name" value="' . $mono_gram_font_graphic_3_sku .'" />
    <label for="graphic-three-name"><img class="image-three-graphics" alt="" height="auto" width="auto" />Three</label>
  </div>


  <div class="parent">
    <div class="one">
      <img src="abc.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="two">
      <img src="xyz.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="three">
      <img src="ghk.jpg">
    </div>

  </div>

  <input type="text" id="testing" value="test" class="imagerep">
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make this more generic - use classes so you do not have to bind to each radio separately.

I have commented code below for you to see what is happening

```js
var radios = $('.graph-init'), // radio buttons
  testing = $('#testing'),
  divs = $('.parent').children(); // image divs

radios.on('change', function() { // bind to all radio inputs
  if (this.checked) {            // only do this if the radio is checked
    divs.hide();                 // hide image divs
    var index = radios.index($(this)); // get the index of the current radio
    var div = divs.eq(index);     // get corresponding div - assumes divs are in same order as radios and equal number of divs
    
    div.show();                   // show div
    
    var imageSource = div.children('img').attr('src');  // get image source - assumes only one image per and image is direct child of div div
    
    testing.val(imageSource); // set testing value
  }
});
```

```css
.one,
.two,
.three {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.two {
  background: #023432
}

.three {
  background: red
}

.one {
  background: #fff
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="graphics-select">
  <div>
    <input class="graph-init" type="radio" name="graphic-one-name" id="graphic-one-name" value="' . $mono_gram_font_graphic_1_sku . '" />
    <label for="graphic-one-name"><img class="image-one-graphics"  alt="" height="auto" width="auto" />One</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="graph-init" type="radio" name="graphic-one-name" id="graphic-two-name" value="' . $mono_gram_font_graphic_2_sku .'" />
    <label for="graphic-two-name"><img class="image-two-graphics"  alt="" height="auto" width="auto" />Two</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="graph-init" type="radio" name="graphic-one-name" id="graphic-three-name" value="' . $mono_gram_font_graphic_3_sku .'" />
    <label for="graphic-three-name"><img class="image-three-graphics" alt="" height="auto" width="auto" />Three</label>
  </div>


  <div class="parent">
    <div class="one">
      <img src="abc.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="two">
      <img src="xyz.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="three">
      <img src="ghk.jpg">
    </div>

  </div>

  <input type="text" id="testing" value="test" class="imagerep">
```